# SonarQube: No DSM data available for the component

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to see the dependencies in SonarQube (referredto as spagetti design at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Cycles+-+Dependency+Structure+Matrix and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Dashboards#ProjectDashboards-SpaghettiDesign).

But when going to a Project, and choosing "Design" in the menu, I receive the message "No DSM data available for the component".

Maybe related to it: I can only find a widget called "File Design", not "Package Design", although from it's description it looks to be similar or the same?

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.1 and have 4 plugins installed:
Findbugs    2.4
Issues Report   1.3
Java    2.4
Sonargraph  3.3

Thanks a lot and regards,

Pieter

Comment: How are you running the analysis? With Maven?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not using Maven, just analyzing on the source code directly. Do you need Maven for that?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to have DSM information, your source code needs to be compiled and the `sonar.binaries` property must point to the folder where the byte code is.

May you use Maven, Ant, Gradle or simply the SonarQube Runner, please first compile your code if you want the DSM.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. I'm using Sonar with a very simple Gradle-controlled Java project. `sonar.binaries` is automatically set to `<<project directory>>\\build\\classes\\main`. However, this project is so simple that I don't believe there are any inter-package dependencies, so is that still a possible reason why I'm getting this issue? I'm using Sonar 5.0.1 with Gradle 2.2.1.